# Определите части речи в пословице

Tags: части-речи

Одна голова хорошо, а две лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Одна-количественное числительное

голова - существительное

хорошо - краткое прилагательное, т.к. обозначает признак предмета, обозначенного сочетанием "одна голова".Одна голова - это каково? - хорошо. Ср.: Всё это хорошо -прилагательное.

Это не категория состояния, потому что это не состояние человека(мне хорошо) и не состояние природы.

а - союз

две - числительное

лучше - сравнительная степень прилагательного.

Answer (score 1):

**Одна голова хорошо, а две лучше.**

Одна голова, две (головы) ― количественно-именное сочетание в роли подлежащего (числительное + существителное).

Хорошо ― **наречие** в роли сказуемого, лучше ― **сравнительная степень наречия** в роли сказуемого.